# GSL solving ODE for a pendulum movement

Tags: c, gsl, ode, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a differential equation for a pendulum movement, given the pendulum initial angle (x), gravity acceleration (g), line length (l), and a time step (h). I've tried this one using Euler method and everything's alright. But now i am to use Runge-Kutta method implemented in GSL. I've tried to implement it learning from the gsl manual, but I'm stuck at one problem. The pendulum doesn't want to stop. Let's say that I start it with initial angle 1 rad, it always has it's peak tilt at 1 rad, no matter how many swings it already did. Here's the equation and the function i use to give it to GSL:

```
x''(t) + g/l*sin(x(t)) = 0
```

transforming it:

```
x''(t) = -g/l*sin(x(t))
```

and decomposing:

```
y(t) = x'(t)
y'(t) = -g/l*sin(x(t))
```

Here's the code snippet, if that's not enough i can post the whole program (it's not too long), but maybe here's the problem somewhere:

```
    int func (double t, const double x[], double dxdt[], void *params){
        double l = *(double*) params;
        double g = *(double*) (params+sizeof(double));
        dxdt[0] = x[1];
        dxdt[1] = -g/l*sin(x[0]);
        return GSL_SUCCESS;
    }
```

The parameters `g` and `l` are passed correctly to the function, I've already checked that.

Comment: In the absence of friction, this is exactly what you should expect.

Comment: Hmm, haven't thought about it this way, but you're probably right. Why  the other way of solving it (with Euler method) causes it to stop finally then? Maybe I've made a mistake somewhere, but yes, you're perfectly right i think. It seems like the other program is bugged, not this one. I'm so silly... If I did this program first and then the other one, maybe I wouldn't be influenced by the eventual stop of the pendulum and think it over before writing here. Thank you!

Comment: Great question. Although the premise was incorrect, I learned a lot from it! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Barton Chittenden noted in a comment, the pendulum *should* keep going in the absence of friction.  This is expected.

As for why it slows and stops when you use the Euler method, that's touching on a subtle and interesting subject.  A (ideal, friction-free) physical pendulum has the property that energy in the system is conserved.  Different integration schemes preserve that property to different degrees.  With some integration schemes, the energy in the system will *grow*, and the pendulum will swing progressively higher.  With others, energy is lost, and the pendulum comes to a halt.  The speed at which either of these happens depends partially on the order of the method; a more accurate method will often lose energy more slowly.

You can easily observe this by plotting the total energy in your system (potential + kinetic) for different integration schemes.

Finally, there is a whole fascinating sub-field of integration methods which preserve certain conserved quantities of a system like this, called symplectic methods.

Comment: Wow, that's a great explanation. It seems I'll have an explanation for my teacher why those two programs work differently. I'll try to find something more about this energy loss when using Euler method. Thank you very much!